# Probability of buying same lottery ticket twice or more using random picker

Tags: probability

This question is inspired by [Jordan Ellenberg's book](https://www.amazon.co.uk/How-Not-Be-Wrong-Everyday/dp/071819604X) from 2014.

> Suppose a lottery cartel buys $300,000$ tickets using a generator
>   which assigns tickets at random. There are $10 \: \text{million}$
>   possible ticket combinations. What is the likelihood that the lottery
>   cartel buys the same ticket twice, i.e., one repeated pair? What is
>   the probability of $n$ repeated pairs of tickets?
>
> Furthermore, what is the expected number of repeated pairs?

---

In principle, the first question is a simple calculation. Using pairings of tickets, I arrived at this being a near certainty, as for every possible pairing of the $300,000$ there is a $\frac{1}{10,000,000}$ chance that this is a repeated pair. There are $^{300,000}C_2$ possible pairs to check. Attempting to evaluate the probability that at least one of these is a repeated pair on a calculator gives $1$, a virtual certainty.

However I'm less sure about how to generalise this to the probability that there are two or more pairs of repeated tickets. I'm also interested in the cleanest formulation of the same ticket being repeated *three* times, i.e. repeated triplets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any two tickets, the probability that they have the same lottery numbers is $p = 10^{-7}$, and there are $n = \binom{300,000}{2} \approx 4.5 \times 10^{10}$ pairs of tickets, so the total number of matching pairs has an approximately binomial distribution with mean $\mu = np \approx 4500$ and standard deviation $\sigma = \sqrt{n p (1-p)} \approx 67.1$.  This is not exact, because the events of matching pairs are not independent, but for such a large number of pairs, they are close to independent.  For a binomial distribution with such a large mean, you could reasonably approximate it with a normal distribution with the same mean and standard deviation.  If you ask for the probability that there are exactly $x$ matching pairs, the probability can be found with the normal distribution but is bound to be very small for any given value of $x$. You may also ask for the probability that the number of matching pairs is within $4500 \pm 50$, for example, and find an answer using the normal distribution.

For repeated triples, the probability that three tickets chosen at random have the same lottery numbers is $p=(10^{-7})^2 = 10^{-14}$, and there are $n = \binom{300,000}{3} \approx 4.5 \times 10^{15}$ triples of tickets, so the total number of matching triples has an approximate binomial distribution with mean $\mu = np \approx 45.0$ and standard deviation $\sigma =\sqrt{n p (1-p)}\approx 6.71$.  Just as in the case of the pairs, you could approximate this distribution with a normal distribution with the same mean and standard deviation.